# During a test is there a way to return to my app if another app (google docs) is opened by an action in my app

Tags: android-espresso

My app has a function where the user needs to accept some terms so when tapping the button to start accepting this item a pdf is opened in google docs to show the user terms where they must then tap the back button either of the device or on google docs. In Espresso I am trying to build a test that follows this path but Espresso locks up and will not leave google docs even if I have inserted a pressBack command.

Is it possible for me to simply resume my activity? Once the user presses back on the document they have to tap "I accept" on my app.

I thought about using stubbed intent but not sure how I can stub it since this is just setup for the app to go straight to the terms when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

If the Google Doc is a WebView, you will have to use [Espresso Web](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web) to interact with the DOM.

```
 onWebView(withId(R.id.google_doc_web_view))
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "back_button"))
        .perform(webClick())
```

Though I would be surprised if this snippet wouldn't work for backing out of the Google Doc:

```
  public static void pressBack() {
        onView(isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.pressBack());
  }
```

Also available within the AndroidX Test framework is [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing)

```
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.pressBack();
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, I will see if I can get one of these things to work out. I have been thinking about whether I should try to convert to AndroidX before I get to far along.
In this case the Activity that is being opened is "com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity" in package  "com.google.android.apps.docs"

Comment: @JoeBertschinger This should work with ATSL as well! Let me know how it goes.